# Sharepoint o365 Publishing infrastructure Global Navigation Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, global-navigation

I have turn on Sharepoint Publishing Infrastruction Features on my site collection.

I notice that sharepoint added a single global navigation link "/sites/xxxx" to it and i can seems to find a way to remove it.

Any ideas?

[image: Sites URL]

[image: Nothing in the Global Navigation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default top left global nav link should be the title of the site.  What is your site title?  Can you ensure your site is set to structural nav and try renaming your site?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Its my mistake, so basically in case anyone else have the same issue as me.

I notice that Title of the Site is not set up.

Site Setting - > Title, description and Logo.

Once the title is input. It will fix the issue.